# Javascript Have to Click Button Twice to Get Dynamic Script to Load and Run

Tags: javascript, button, dynamic, loading

First time I click the button, nothing.  Second time i click the code runs.  I run the page test.html in chrome or IE, it doesn't matter.  How can i get the code in the loaded script to run the first click?  I'm a js noob.

```
/* test.html */
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
  <title>start</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="t01.js">
</script>
</head>
<body>
   <input type="text" id="txt1" />
        <input type="button" id="submit" onclick="getSent(document.getElementById('txt1').value)"
            value=" OK " />
    <div id="reply">reply</div>
</body>
</html>


/* t01.js */
window.onload = function () {
}
function getSent(str) {
    while (1) {

        load_script("relg.js");
        dof();

        reply = "Reached end of loop.";
        break;
    } // end main loop
    document.getElementById("reply").innerHTML = reply;

}
function load_script(filename){
  var fileref=document.createElement('script');
  fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
  fileref.setAttribute("src", filename);
  if (typeof fileref!="undefined")
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref);
}

/* relg.js */
function dof() {
    alert("b");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script needs some time to load, try something like this:

```
function getSent(str) {
    load_script("relg.js");
    return; 
}
function load_script(filename){
    var fileref=document.createElement('script');
    fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
    fileref.onload = function () {
        dof();
        return;
    }
    fileref.setAttribute("src", filename);
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref);
}
```

Another alternative is to create an IIFE (Immediately-Invoked Function Expression) to the `regl.js`, and not invoke `dof()` at all in main script:

```
(function dof() {
    alert("b");
}());
```

Now `dof()` will be executed as soon as it is parsed to the page.